# CSS Bar Chart: highlight every column of the same series on hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, bar-chart

I got a **`CSS`** bar chart and I want to change it on `hover`.

First I want all the colors to get `opacity` set to `0.5 on hover` (ease!), after that I want the hovered series (every bars of the same color) to get its `opacity to 1`.

I am also looking for a way to make that work with the chart's legend as well.

```css
body{margin:0}
.row{width:100%;display:inline-flex}
.container{width:100%;max-width:730px;float:left;margin:auto}

.chart{width:100%;height:300px;display:inline-flex;margin-bottom:80px;position:relative}
.group{position:relative;width:8%;height:100%;margin:0 1%;display:inline-flex}
[class*="bar"]{position:absolute;width:49.9999%;margin:0;opacity:1;bottom:0;transition:all 2s ease;max-height:0}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(1){background-color:#ff7777}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(2){background-color:#77b8ff;margin-left:50%}

.bar-341{height:85.25%}
.bar-278{height:69.5%}
.bar-264{height:66%}
.bar-246{height:61.5%}
.bar-189{height:47.25%}
.bar-137{height:34.25%}
.bar-105{height:26.25%}
.bar-102{height:25.5%}
.bar-92{height:23%}
.bar-58{height:14.5%}
.bar-49{height:12.25%}
.bar-43{height:10.75%}
.bar-37{height:9.25%}
.bar-18{height:4.5%}
.bar-14{height:3.5%}
.bar-10{height:2.5%}
.bar-6{height:1.5%}
.bar-5{height:1.25%}
.bar-3{height:0.75%}
.bar-2{height:0.5%}
.grouptxt{position:absolute;top:105%;width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:.95em}
.txtlabel{position:absolute;top:-30px;left:50%;width:100%;margin-left:-50%!important;text-align:center;font-size:.95em;transition:all 1s ease;opacity:0}
.legend{display:inline-block;position:absolute;top:17.5%;right:12.5%}
.leg{font-size:.95em;padding:5px}
.leg1:before,.leg2:before{width:25px;height:25px;margin:1px;content:'';position:absolute;left:-30px;margin-top:-3px;transition:all 2s ease}
.leg1:before{background-color:#ff7777}
.leg2:before{background-color:#77b8ff}
@media only screen and (max-width:750px){.grouptxt,.txtlabel{font-size:.8em;transform:rotate(-90deg);text-align:end}.grouptxt{top:110%}.chart{margin-bottom:90px}}
.chart [class*="bar"]{max-height:300px}
.chart .txtlabel{opacity:.8}

.chart:hover [class*="bar"]{opacity:.5}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(1):hover{opacity:1}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(2):hover{opacity:1}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(1):hover .txtlabel{opacity:1}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(2):hover .txtlabel{opacity:1}

.chart:hover .leg1:before,.chart:hover .leg2:before{opacity:.5}
```

```html
<div class='row'><div class='container'>
<div class='chart'>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='bar-341 bar1'><div class='txtlabel'>34,1</div></div>
    <div class='bar-278'><div class='txtlabel'>27,8</div></div>
    <div class='grouptxt'>A pé</div>
  </div>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='bar-246 bar1'><div class='txtlabel'>24,6</div></div>
    <div class='bar-189'><div class='txtlabel'>18,9</div></div>
    <div class='grouptxt'>Ônibus</div>
  </div>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='bar-137'><div class='txtlabel'>13,7</div></div>
    <div class='bar-264'><div class='txtlabel'>26,4</div></div>
    <div class='grouptxt'>Carro motorista</div>
  </div>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='bar-105'><div class='txtlabel'>10,5</div></div>
    <div class='bar-58'><div class='txtlabel'>5,8</div></div>
    <div class='grouptxt'>Carro passageiro</div>
  </div>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='bar-102'><div class='txtlabel'>10,2</div></div>
    <div class='bar-92'><div class='txtlabel'>9,2</div></div>
    <div class='grouptxt'>Metrô</div>
  </div>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='bar-43'><div class='txtlabel'>4,3</div></div>
    <div class='bar-49'><div class='txtlabel'>4,9</div></div>
    <div class='grouptxt'>Escolar</div>
  </div>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='bar-14'><div class='txtlabel'>1,4</div></div>
    <div class='bar-18'><div class='txtlabel'>1,8</div></div>
    <div class='grouptxt'>Trem</div>
  </div>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='bar-6'><div class='txtlabel'>0,6</div></div>
    <div class='bar-37'><div class='txtlabel'>3,7</div></div>
    <div class='grouptxt'>Moto</div>
  </div>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='bar-5'><div class='txtlabel'>0,5</div></div>
    <div class='bar-3'><div class='txtlabel'>0,3</div></div>
    <div class='grouptxt'>Táxi</div>
  </div>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='bar-2'><div class='txtlabel'>0,2</div></div>
    <div class='bar-10'><div class='txtlabel'>1,0</div></div>
    <div class='grouptxt'>Bicicleta</div>
  </div>
  <div class='legend'>
    <div class='leg leg1'>Mulheres</div>
    <div class='leg leg2'>Homens</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Your principal issue here is that CSS does not have 360 degree selectors. You can influence the presentation of an element, that element's subsequent siblings or that element's children. You cannot influence the presentation of that element's previous siblings or ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to solve this:

```js
$('.red-bar').hover(
    function(){
          $('.red-bar, .leg1').css({"opacity":"1"});
          $('head').append('<style>.leg1:before{opacity:1;} </style>');
          $('.blue-bar, .leg2').css({"opacity":".5"});
    },function(){
        $('.red-bar, .leg1').css({"opacity":"1"});
        $('.blue-bar, .leg2').css({"opacity":"1"});
});

    $('.blue-bar').hover(
    function(){
          $('.blue-bar, .leg2').css({"opacity":"1"});
          $('head').append('<style>.leg2:before{opacity:1;}</style>');
          $('.red-bar, .leg1').css({"opacity":".5"});
    },function(){
        $('.red-bar, .leg1').css({"opacity":"1"});
        $('.blue-bar, .leg2').css({"opacity":"1"});
});
```

```css
body{margin:0}
.row{width:100%;display:inline-flex}
.container{width:100%;max-width:730px;float:left;margin:auto}

.chart{width:100%;height:300px;display:inline-flex;margin-bottom:80px;position:relative}
.group{position:relative;width:8%;height:100%;margin:0 1%;display:inline-flex}
[class*="bar"]{position:absolute;width:49.9999%;margin:0;opacity:1;bottom:0;transition:all 2s ease;max-height:0}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(1){background-color:#ff7777}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(2){background-color:#77b8ff;margin-left:50%}

.bar-341{height:85.25%}
.bar-278{height:69.5%}
.bar-264{height:66%}
.bar-246{height:61.5%}
.bar-189{height:47.25%}
.bar-137{height:34.25%}
.bar-105{height:26.25%}
.bar-102{height:25.5%}
.bar-92{height:23%}
.bar-58{height:14.5%}
.bar-49{height:12.25%}
.bar-43{height:10.75%}
.bar-37{height:9.25%}
.bar-18{height:4.5%}
.bar-14{height:3.5%}
.bar-10{height:2.5%}
.bar-6{height:1.5%}
.bar-5{height:1.25%}
.bar-3{height:0.75%}
.bar-2{height:0.5%}
.grouptxt{position:absolute;top:105%;width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:.95em}
.txtlabel{position:absolute;top:-30px;left:50%;width:100%;margin-left:-50%!important;text-align:center;font-size:.95em;transition:all 1s ease;opacity:0}
.legend{display:inline-block;position:absolute;top:17.5%;right:12.5%}
.leg{font-size:.95em;padding:5px}
.leg1:before,.leg2:before{width:25px;height:25px;margin:1px;content:'';position:absolute;left:-30px;margin-top:-3px;transition:all 2s ease}
.leg1:before{background-color:#ff7777; opacity: 1;}
.leg2:before{background-color:#77b8ff; opacity: 1;}
@media only screen and (max-width:750px){.grouptxt,.txtlabel{font-size:.8em;transform:rotate(-90deg);text-align:end}.grouptxt{top:110%}.chart{margin-bottom:90px}}
.chart [class*="bar"]{max-height:300px}
.chart .txtlabel{opacity:.8}

.chart:hover [class*="bar"]{opacity:.5}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(1):hover{opacity:1}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(2):hover{opacity:1}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(1):hover .txtlabel{opacity:1}
[class*="bar"]:nth-child(2):hover .txtlabel{opacity:1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'><div class='container'>
        <div class='chart'>
          <div class='group'>
            <div class='bar-341 bar1 red-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>34,1</div></div>
            <div class='bar-278 blue-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>27,8</div></div>
            <div class='grouptxt'>A pé</div>
          </div>
          <div class='group'>
            <div class='bar-246 bar1 red-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>24,6</div></div>
            <div class='bar-189 blue-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>18,9</div></div>
            <div class='grouptxt'>Ônibus</div>
          </div>
          <div class='group'>
            <div class='bar-137 red-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>13,7</div></div>
            <div class='bar-264 blue-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>26,4</div></div>
            <div class='grouptxt'>Carro motorista</div>
          </div>
          <div class='group'>
            <div class='bar-105 red-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>10,5</div></div>
            <div class='bar-58 blue-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>5,8</div></div>
            <div class='grouptxt'>Carro passageiro</div>
          </div>
          <div class='group'>
            <div class='bar-102 red-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>10,2</div></div>
            <div class='bar-92 blue-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>9,2</div></div>
            <div class='grouptxt'>Metrô</div>
          </div>
          <div class='group'>
            <div class='bar-43 red-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>4,3</div></div>
            <div class='bar-49 blue-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>4,9</div></div>
            <div class='grouptxt'>Escolar</div>
          </div>
          <div class='group'>
            <div class='bar-14 red-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>1,4</div></div>
            <div class='bar-18 blue-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>1,8</div></div>
            <div class='grouptxt'>Trem</div>
          </div>
          <div class='group'>
            <div class='bar-6 red-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>0,6</div></div>
            <div class='bar-37 blue-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>3,7</div></div>
            <div class='grouptxt'>Moto</div>
          </div>
          <div class='group'>
            <div class='bar-5 red-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>0,5</div></div>
            <div class='bar-3 blue-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>0,3</div></div>
            <div class='grouptxt'>Táxi</div>
          </div>
          <div class='group'>
            <div class='bar-2 red-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>0,2</div></div>
            <div class='bar-10 blue-bar'><div class='txtlabel'>1,0</div></div>
            <div class='grouptxt'>Bicicleta</div>
          </div>
          <div class='legend'>
            <div class='leg leg1'>Mulheres</div>
            <div class='leg leg2'>Homens</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```